# Calculating the forecast by hand EGARCH

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch

Have an AR(1)EGARCH(1,1) with:

$r_t=0.000584-0.040705r_{t-1} $

as the mean equation and EGARCH(1,1) with:

$\ln(var_{t})=-0.196215C(3)+0.148447C(4)-0.069507C(5)+0.989870C(6)$

where I assume:

$C(3)=constant, C(4)=(u_{t-1}/st.dev_{t-1}), C(5)=|u_{t-1}/st.dev_{t-1}|-mew$ and $C(6)=ln(var_{t-1})$ and mew=$AR(1)$.

I plugged in 0.007595 as both the $u_{t-1}$ and $r_{t-1}$, as that is the actual value of the previous period's residual. I plugged in the variance as $6.65e-0.5$ which it also gives me, although I am sure this is not relevant in calculating the following period's residual.

I just want to know what I am doing wrong and if I could be given a correct formula or if someone was kind enough to actually work it out. The actual values in the next periods are 0.000219, 0.011441 and -0.003695. The forecasted values are 0.000298, 0.000595 and 0.000583 (from the mean equation). After that, they just equal 0.000584. The following period's conditional variance is 0.0000649 and I got 0.000064845, which would not round so I had a problem, although that was calculated using the mean value from AR(1) equation, as opposed to $sqrt(2/pi)$

I believe I have misunderstood the dependent variable in the AR(1) equation, and clearly misunderstand how to calculate the future forecast of the return. Any help would be massively appreciated, and apologies for the lack of knowledge specifying the symbols for the functions, I have never written equations on this. Currently unsure how to get the forecasted residual.

(Also, if someone could give me an idea of how mew changes if a student-t is assumed, would be great as I currently cannot take care of the excess kurtosis) (Sorry for long question)

*NOTE* Can now calculate the next period's variance and mean, just not the residual! If anyone can help, please do!!